# Kendo UI Treeview and XML Data Source

Tags: xml, treeview, datasource, kendo-ui

I've been reading the existing documentation about the Treeview as well as the Hierarchical Data Source and the Data Source but I am kinda lost it about the possible remote data source types that I can use with the Treeview.

Apart from json, xml is also supported, right? Is it possible to bind it and view the xml file with the Treeview?

I've been trying something like:

```
        <script>
            var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({
                    transport: {
                        read: {
                            url:"http://localhost:8080/OnTheSpotRestfullAPI/testTree.xml"
                        }
                    },
                    schema: {
                        type: "xml",
                        data: "/tree/vehicles",
                        model: {
                            fields: {
                                car: "car/text()",
                                bike: "bike/text()"
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });

            $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
                dataSource: ds
            });
        </script>
```

with the testTree.xml being:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>    
<tree>  
    <vehicles>
        <car>FM-1100</car>
        <car>FM-4200</car>
        <bike>FM-3100</bike>
    </vehicles>
    <personnel>
        <client>GH-3000</client>
        <vip>GH-3100</vip>
    </personnel>
</tree>
```

I want the resulting tree to be something like:

(Vehicles)

--(Cars)

----FM-1100

----FM-4200

--(Bikes)

----FM-3100

(Personnel)

--(Clients)

----GH-3000

--(VIPs)

----GH-3100

PS. Names in () are supposed to be something like folders containing their "children"

but I can't seem to be able to view the tree at all.. Kinda lost here, can someone please point me to the right direction?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just to make sure: you should execute the script code after the html is loaded so you should enclose it in

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        // The JavaScript code goes here
    });
</script>
```

The datasource `ds` should be defined `HierarchicalDataSource` and not `DataSource`.
Reading you XML example I'm not sure how is the hierarchy organized (the tree), what should be the content of the tree.

You might try something like:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function () {
        var ds = new kendo.data.HierarchicalDataSource({
            transport:{
                read:{
                    url:"testTree.xml"
                }
            },
            schema   :{
                type :"xml",
                data :"/tree/vehicles/car",
                model:{
                    fields:{
                        text:"text()"
                    }
                }
            }
        });


        $("#treeview").kendoTreeView({
            dataSource   :ds
        });
    });
</script>
```

And the XML something like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<tree>
    <vehicles>
        <car>FM-1100</car>
        <car>FM-4200</car>
        <bike>FM-3100</bike>
    </vehicles>
    <personnel>
        <client>GH-3000</client>
        <vip>GH-3100</vip>
    </personnel>
</tree>
```

NOTE: Not sure what to do with `bike`

Comment: Indeed your reply showed the two results of the <car> elements.
I edited my question to show how I want the tree.

Comment: You need to do some programming for using your XML as you have defined. `TreeView` and `HierarchicalDataSource` load each node separately: `TreeView` issues a read on `DataSource.transport`for each new node. Said so, you either change your Server code + XML format for accepting something like: give me the children of this node OR you use schema.parse / schema.data for converting your XML into the JSON that TreeView accepts.

Comment: I see,can you please explain a bit more the "change your Server code + XML format for accepting something like: give me the children of this node" part? Also of what i've seen the treeview can't load a whole json file at once but you have to set up a server so it can load one stage of the tree at a time through a callback I think :S

Comment: Basically, when the root of the tree is loaded your server will receive a request with no `id`. Each time that `TreeView` needs to load another node, it will call your server with a parameter (the `id` of the node being loaded). Your server should send the XML of just that part.

Comment: About `TreeView` ability of loading the whole JSON... You can do it by defining your `var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource(...)`, then invoke `ds.read()` and finally get the XML converted to `TreeView` required JSON format. Only then you call `kendoTreeView` with the converted JavaScript array.